# Gradle tasks are not appear in gradle tasks panel

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle

while I'm using my company's gradle, I got a problem.

gradle tasks in Eclipse and Intellij are different.
it means both have less tasks than enough.

what should I check?

left one is Eclipse, and other one is Intellij

[image]

Comment: I think it is caused by exception. if some tasks make exception, it doesn't show in pannel. but I don't know this is accurate.

Comment: What is the exception? In IntelliJ IDEA screenshot I see errors indications in Gradle tool window. What are those, what is the error text? It means that the [importing from Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project) process may have not finished successfully. Btw can you build project from command line?