# Gradle tasks do not appear in the Gradle tasks panel in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

While using IntelliJ and gradle, I run into an issue where gradle tasks do not appear in the gradle tasks window.

For example, where you can usually select project > Tasks > build > clean to clean the project, the "Tasks" option is unavailable.

Example from a similar question across two IDEs:

[image]

What would cause the IntelliJ Gradle panel to not populate?

Comment: Recreated question and answer from unanswered other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167463/gradle-tasks-are-not-appear-in-gradle-tasks-panel

Answer (score 1):

Reload the Gradle project and review the logs. If any exception or issue happens during the loading process, it will result in an unpopulated Gradle tasks panel.